# Can Grafana communicate with InfluxDB over https?

Tags: security, https, grafana, influxdb

I have a working setup where Grafana connects to an InfluxDB data source via http. I'd like to secure the communication between Grafana and InfluxDB by using **https**. I have enabled https in the InfluxDB configuration and can connect to the InfluxDB instance via the URL `https://<domain_name>.com:8086`. However, when configuring the https URL in Grafana the connection test fails. It appears as if Grafana can't connect via https.

Many thanks for your advise.

Comment: What kind of error? CORS, cert issue. ...?

Comment: I receive an `"Network Error: Bad Gateway(502)"` message when I configure InfluxDB as a data source and press "Save & Test".

Comment: I am getting the following error:
`Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.`

Any idea on this?

Comment: This sounds like you configured Grafana (the client) to use http and InfluxDB to use https. Does the problem go away if you configure Grafana to use https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.

As this is a test server, I configured HTTPS with a self-signed certificate (see also [Enabling HTTPS with InfluxDB](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/administration/https_setup/#sidebar), section *"Set up HTTPS with a self-signed certificate"*).

It looks like Grafana throws a `Network Error: Bad Gateway(502)` message if a certificate is issued by an authority that is not trusted.

I solved this by installing the self-signed certificate as a root certificate following this guideline: [How do I install a root certificate?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate). Please note this is not recommended for production systems.